# WinHttpRequest.ResponseText returns truncated text

Tags: vba, excel, web-services

I trying to call web-service in my Excel macro. The call works fine except that the response is truncated (the whole response is about 2 megabytes).

Here's the Procedure i'm using

```
Sub CallWebService(xmlRequest As String)

    Dim pRequest As New WinHttpRequest

    pRequest.Open "GET", "http://my-url-here", True
    pRequest.SetRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "groupRequest"
    pRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
    pRequest.Send xmlRequest
    pRequest.WaitForResponse (100)

     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value = pRequest.ResponseText

End Sub
```

How to get the whole response text?

Comment: Is it `pRequest.ResponseText` that is truncated, or the contents of `Range("A1").Value`? IOW if you dump the response text into a text file, is it truncated?

Comment: Max length of text in a cell is 32,000 characters I think.  Try adding `Debug.Print Len(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value), Len(pRequest.ResponseText)`

Comment: put `pRequest.ResponseText` into a variable first, then you can check the length of the variable

Comment: You are right. Post this comment as an answer for me to accept it.